# Is there a way to grant access to a shared directory on network for kiosk users?

Tags: windows, permission-denied, kiosk-mode, shared-directory

I'm struggling with granting access to a shared folder on network for all kiosk users in windows10. But it keeps giving the error:

> We can't open '\\192.168.100.135\SharedProjects'. Your organization has blocked it.

I have already given the `everyone` full access to `SharedProjects`  and can access it in other normal (nonkiosk) user accounts. Also Refering to [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1318432/accessing-a-shared-directory-in-explorer-in-window), I set some registry keys relating to `Map Network Drive`. My XML file for setting kiosk mode for kiosk user is as follows. It runs correctly in Windows powershell.

```
$nameSpaceName="root\cimv2\mdm\dmmap"
$className="MDM_AssignedAccess"
$obj = Get-CimInstance -Namespace $namespaceName -ClassName $className
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Web
$obj.Configuration = [System.Web.HttpUtility]::HtmlEncode(@"
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<AssignedAccessConfiguration 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/AssignedAccess/2017/config"
    xmlns:rs5="http://schemas.microsoft.com/AssignedAccess/201810/config"
    >
      <Profiles>
        <Profile Id="{9A2A490F-10F6-4764-974A-43B19E722C23}">
          <AllAppsList>
            <AllowedApps>
              <App AppUserModelId="Microsoft.ZuneMusic_8wekyb3d8bbwe!Microsoft.ZuneMusic" />
              <App AppUserModelId="Microsoft.ZuneVideo_8wekyb3d8bbwe!Microsoft.ZuneVideo" />
              <App AppUserModelId="Microsoft.Windows.Photos_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App" />
              <App AppUserModelId="Microsoft.BingWeather_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App" />
              <App AppUserModelId="Microsoft.WindowsCalculator_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App" />    
              <App DesktopAppPath="C:\Windows\system32\notepad.exe" />            
              <App DesktopAppPath="C:\Windows\explorer.exe" />                    
             </AllowedApps>
          </AllAppsList>
          <rs5:FileExplorerNamespaceRestrictions>
            <rs5:AllowedNamespace Name="Downloads"/>            
          </rs5:FileExplorerNamespaceRestrictions>
          <StartLayout>
            <![CDATA[<LayoutModificationTemplate xmlns:defaultlayout="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Start/2014/FullDefaultLayout" xmlns:start="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Start/2014/StartLayout" Version="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Start/2014/LayoutModification">
                          <LayoutOptions StartTileGroupCellWidth="6" />
                          <DefaultLayoutOverride>
                            <StartLayoutCollection>
                              <defaultlayout:StartLayout GroupCellWidth="6">                        
                                <start:Group Name="Group2">                                                               
                                  <start:DesktopApplicationTile Size="2x2" Column="2" Row="0" DesktopApplicationLinkPath="%appdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Accessories\explorer.lnk" />
                                  <start:DesktopApplicationTile Size="2x2" Column="4" Row="0" DesktopApplicationLinkPath="%appdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Accessories\SharedProjects.lnk" />
                                  <start:DesktopApplicationTile Size="2x2" Column="6" Row="0" DesktopApplicationLinkPath="C:\Windows\system32\notepad.exe" />
                                </start:Group>
                              </defaultlayout:StartLayout>
                            </StartLayoutCollection>
                          </DefaultLayoutOverride>
                        </LayoutModificationTemplate>
                    ]]>
          </StartLayout>
          <Taskbar ShowTaskbar="true"/>
        </Profile>
        </Profiles>
      <Configs>
        <Config>
          <Account>DESKTOP-M3UAQ1N\kiosk</Account>
          <DefaultProfile Id="{9A2A490F-10F6-4764-974A-43B19E722C23}"/>
        </Config>   
      </Configs>
</AssignedAccessConfiguration>
"@)

Set-CimInstance -CimInstance $obj
```